# Wiki Page Library issue in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would really appreciate it if someone would help me out with this issue.

I'm using SharePoint 2010. I created a Wiki Page Library without changing any of the library settings, and created a new Wiki page, all that went fine but once I started adding text and then tried to save the changes on the page, this message appears:

> "You must specify a value for this required field"

I don't know what to do, there is no required field and I can't really fix that... so please help me with that message!!

Answer (score 1):

Fatima, I don't know if you ever got your question answered, but this is a known issue with Publishing features. There is a field that is marked as required, but is not displayed on the page. I beleive it's the column/field called "Name". If you look through the Site Content Types and find "wiki page", you'll see that status is marked as "Required". Changing that should fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a Place holder missing from the Main area of your master page.

Even if you’ve moved it to a asp:Panel and declared it as false at the bottom of your master page you’ll still get the error.

All you need is to move content place holder

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id=“PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea” runat=”server”></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

within the ***s4-bodyContainer*** div , within the ***s4-ca*** div seems to work best. Save the master page and that’s it. that no more irritating message.

Reference: http://sharepointbrandingteam.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/sharepoint-2010-error-you-must-specify-a-value-for-this-required-field/

Alternatively, you can try the solution suggested [here](http://alispasset.blogspot.sg/2011/11/you-must-specify-value-for-this.html)